# Rails: will_paginate + simple search engine error: undefined method `total_pages'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

on my users index page I am trying to have a search engine at the top so that you can search a user by email instead of scanning through the whole list. However, I am getting the error:

`undefined method 'total_pages'`

when I search any term.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

users/index.html.erb

```
<h1>All users</h1>

<%= form_tag users_path, :method => "get" do %>
    <%= label_tag(:search, "Search for user by email:") %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>

<%= will_paginate @users %>
<br>

<% @users.each do |user| %>
<div>
<%= link_to (image_tag user.profilepic? ? user.profilepic : "questionmark.png", :size => "50x50"), user_path(user) %>
<%= link_to user.name, user_path(user) %> (<%= user.email %>)
<% unless current_user.friends.include?(user) || current_user == user %>
<span class="floatright"><%= link_to "Add friend", user_friends_path(:user_id => current_user.id, :friend_id => user.id), :method => :post %></span>
<% end %>
<% if current_user.friends.include?(user) %>
<span class="floatright"><%= link_to "Remove friend", user_friends_path(:user_id => current_user.id, :friend_id => user.id), :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure you want to remove #{user.name} from your friends?" %></span>
<% end %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

users controller

```
def index
  if params[:search]
    @users = User.search(params[:search])
  else
    @users = User.order("email").page(params[:page]).per_page(10)
  end
end
```

user model

```
  def self.search(search)
    find(:all, :conditions => ['email LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calling a pagination method in `@users = User.search(params[:search])`. Try adding the `.page(params[:page]).per_page(10)` and see if that works.

**UPDATE:**

Sorry, I forgot `.find` returns an array and not a relation. Change your search method to this:

```
def self.search(search)
  where('email LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
end
```

Comment: hey zach. it still gives me `undefined method `page' for #<Array:0x007fcd80b93390>` when I change the third line of the index action of the controller to `@users = User.search(params[:search]).page(params[:page]).per_page(10)`